# Powersheel script to fetch logs from remote desktop

Tags: powershell

We are working on one application and for that application there is one module called replicator and this replicator shows the status whether failed or successful in every h hrs it runs. So, I want to create a powershell script which will check the logs from my remote desktop server and email me the status of replicator .

Can somebody help me in this.

Comment: Please read the help about asking [good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your post accordingly. As of now, there isn't an exact question but a generic problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

Are the logs in a text file?  Does it have a particular format?  Something like:

```
$logline = Get-Content \\path\to\file.txt -Last 1
Send-MailMessage -smtpserver smtp0 -from me@me.com -to me@me.com -Subject "Latest Result is $logline"
```